# GeoDjango: How to get area of all object in a model?

Tags: area, geodjango

We can get the area of a specific pin by this:

```
>>> from tbl.models import *
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
>>> pnt = ButuanMaps.objects.get(clandpin='162-03-0001-017-33').geom
>>> pnt = ButuanMaps.objects.get(clandpin='162-03-0001-017-33')
>>> pnt = ButuanMaps.objects.get(clandpin='162-03-0001-017-33').geom
>>> pnt.area
4947.0185203032115
```

How about getting all the area of all the pins?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
>>> distincts = ButuanMaps.objects.order_by('id').values_list('clandpin', flat=True)[:10]
>>> for value in distincts:print (reduce(lambda a,x: x.calculated_area.sq_m, ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=value).area(model_att='calculated_area'), Area(0)),value)
```